# Error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" al consumir un servicio REST API con el metodo POST en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

Estoy consumiendo un servicio REST API con AngularJS y el metodo **POST**, al consumir el servicio me esta saliendo el siguiente error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://..... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost:28187 is therefore not allowed access.

Ya he leido y evidentemente es un problema de **CORS** puesto que al enviar la peticion y el servidor contesta, la cabecera Access-Control-Allow-Origin debe contener en este caso mi IP (o la ip de la aplicación de angularjs) o debe contener algo como `Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"`.

Ya revise en el browser y efectivamente la respuesta que me envia el servidor no contiene el `Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"`, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Imagen Response]

La solucion obvia es configurar en el servidor donde estan los servicios **REST** la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` pero desafortunadamente este es un servidor de un proveedor externo en el que no ha sido facil que hagan el cambio.

Quiero saber si existe alguna manera en AngularJS que me permita solucionar este problema en el cliente y no seguir esperando que me hagan el cambio en el servidor.

Comment: Crea un proxy y agrega dicha directiva, necesitarás para ello un entorno en el lado servidor (php, nodejs, python, ruby, etc)

Comment: No hay nada que se pueda hacer desde la aplicación angular, esto es siempre problema del servidor, habla con tu proveedor

Answer (score 5):

En Chrome, instala esta extensión [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)  La activas y podrás permitir conexiones entre dominios.

[image: Activando extensión]

Comment: This works for me. :D

Comment: This works for me too! Perfect!

Answer (score -1):

Nada lo mas fácil en tu **php** del lado del servidor al inicio del `<?php
ob_start()`;

Tus contenido y al final

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Eso es todo.

Answer (score -2):

Este es un error de dominio en el request que realizas

1. Publica tu sitio en el mismo dominio del servidor, por ejemplo si el servidor es

> http://www.dominio.com

publica tu desarrollo en

> http://desarrollo.dominio.com

Añadiendo en el archivo host (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts ) de su maquina lo siguiente.

```
#   127.0.0.1       desarrollo.dominio.com
```

con esto el request queda de salida desde el mismo dominio del servidor y eliminas el CORS

Comment: esta no es una respuesta valida ; coloca una respuesta valida o elimina esta respuesta

Comment: No valida? no puede cambiar la configuración  CORS en el servidor. cuales son sus argumentos para que la respuesta no sea valida?

Comment: crees que probando con postman es la solucion?, esta diciendo que es un servicio externo y depende de alguien; eso quiere decir que no puede estar instalandole el CORS a todos

Comment: necesitamos descartar escenarios! has leido toda la respuesta?

Comment: lo que hicistes es un comentario cuando tengas privilegios podras agregar comentarios

Comment: Para eso es el plug-in!!! es solución del lado del cliente o el cambio en el host.

Comment: Creo que esto es un comentario, mas que una respuesta ya que no se da una solución concreta.

Comment: Wilfredo tiene razón, pero no tengo puntos para publicar comentarios en el foro en español, solo intento ayudar! buena suerte ojala le ayuden a ivan dario y no solo den calificaciones negativas a las repuestas! :D

Comment: @CristhianCamiloGómezNarváez lo que comentas es útil, pero debes tener un poco de paciencia para obtener reputación y eso se realiza siguiendo lo que dicta el [help] ,saludos!.

Comment: seguramente me dirán lo mismo, que esto que comento no es una respuesta válida, pero es bien recibido por parte de cualquier usuario, el aporte que da @Cristhian Camilo Gómez Narváez es útil, no entiendo el porque algún moderador pudiera decir que no es respuesta cuando el que decide es el propio usuario que realizó la pregunta, si al le funcionó, si a el le solucionó, entonces es una respuesta válida

Comment: @AlfonsoCastañeda te equivocas. Este sitio tiene unas normas claras en cuanto a lo que es una respuesta y lo que no, puedes leerlo en [answer]. Y si, el usuario que pregunta tiene la opción de marcar una respuesta como válida, pero no es el unico que decide. Todos los usuarios con sus votos son los que deciden, y además, el sitio lo que busca no es solo ayudar al usuario que pregunta, sino a todo aquel que en el futuro tenga la misma duda y pueda llegar a esta pregunta y resolverlo. Por eso las respuestas deben ser claras e inequivocas. Un saludo